# How to set up local DNS server with conditional forwarding?

Tags: mac, dns, forwarding

I'm trying to set up a DNS server that will forward some but not all lookups to Google's 8.8.8.8 DNS server, mapping a few specific domain names to other IP addresses (of my choosing) instead.  I have been trying this with both `dnsmasq` and BIND, but the configuration files are very confusing to me for both.

Comment: I can help with bind - what do you have so far?

Comment: You're DNS server, by design, will forward anything it can't look up locally to it's forwarding server. So if your local DNS says that google.com is 1.2.3.4, then it will send back 1.2.3.4 as the return. Everything else that it doesn't have a record for will get sent to 8.8.8.8 for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I add an answer in case someone comes across this, and is looking for a solution. On Windows the conditional forwarding can be set up by using a commercial [Simple DNS Plus](http://simpledns.com/) program. It offers DNS forwarding by domain name, plus a catch-all.

On Linux/Mac you can use bind (named). See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/99111/46754) for details.